# Install an application into windows registry with Fasm

Tags: fasm

I am trying to install my application written in Fasm into windows registry using RegCreateKeyExA and RegSetValueExA. These APIs return success however the registry key is not created. This is part of source:

```
hRegKey dd 0
disp dd 0
SubKey db "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run",0
TestKey db "TestString",0
StringToWrite db "c:\aplicativo.exe",0   
invoke RegCreateKeyExA,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,SubKey,\
0,0,REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL,hRegKey, disp
invoke lstrlen,StringToWrite
invoke RegSetValueExA,[hRegKey], TestKey, 0, REG_SZ,\ 
StringToWrite, eax
invoke RegCloseKey,[hRegKey]
```

Why RegSetValueEx don't create the registry key?